# Collapsible jQuery drop down menu - stop event propagation

Tags: jquery, wordpress, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

I have been working on making a Wordpress custom theme responsive.  Because of the way the them is used on the multisite install I felt the best approach would be to get the main menu to turn into a collapsible drop down on smaller screens.
I am a bit of a jQuery newbie but after a few failed attempts I have managed to write my own scrip which controls collapsible menus using the parent / child.
So here is my question.  When there is an item without sub-menus is there a way for jQuery to detect there's no child elements and allow clicking through to the link instead?
Here is my code:

```
<a href="#navigation" class="mobile-nav-link">Navigation</a>
<nav id="access" class="menu" role="navigation">
<div id="nav-wrap-mobile">
<div id="nav-wrap-sub-mobile">
<div class="menu-main-menu-2-container">
<ul id="menu-main-menu-5" class="menu">
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-37"><a href="http://link.to.thing">Parent 1</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1877"><a href="http://link.to.thing">Child 1</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<ul id="menu-main-menu-5" class="menu">
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-38"><a href="http://link.to.thing">Parent 1</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1879"><a href="http://link.to.thing">Child 2</a>
</li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1878"><a href="http://link.to.thing">Child 2</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<ul id="menu-main-menu-7" class="menu">
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-37"><a href="http://link.to.thing">No Parent</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
    </div>
</nav>
<!-- #access- -->
```

And here is the jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$('#nav-wrap-mobile').hide();
$('.mobile-nav-link').click(function() {
$('#nav-wrap-mobile').toggle();
});
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$('ul.sub-menu').hide();
$('ul.menu').children().click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(this).children('ul.sub-menu').toggle();}).children('ul.sub-menu').click(function (event) { 
 event.stopPropagation();
    });
   });
  });
```

Here's a Jsfiddle that illustrates what I am trying to say:

http://jsfiddle.net/nivims/S48ZV/15/

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Add this to your `children().click()` function before `e.preventDefault();` : `if ($(this).find("[class*=menu]").length == 0) return true;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can need to check whether there is a sub list, add this:

```
if ($(this).children('ul').length == 0) {
    return;
}
```

to right underneath:

```
$('ul.menu').children().click(function (e) {
```